# XPath point to element in table next to specific

Tags: xpath

I have HTML structure like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>some value 1</td>
        <td>unique value 1</td>
        <td>needed value 1</td>
        <td>some value 1</td>
    </tr>


    <tr>
        <td>some value 2</td>
        <td>unique value 2</td>
        <td>needed value 2</td>
        <td>some value 2</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>some value 3</td>
        <td>unique value 3</td>
        <td>needed value 3</td>
        <td>some value 3</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

I use Selenium and need to point to td next to unique value by searching this unique value using XPath.

I have found solution: find tr with needed unique value, then count td's preceding-sibling and use position()=count(preceding-sibling)+2

```
//tr[./td[text()='Unique value 2']]/td[position()=count(//tr[./td[text()='Unique value 2']]/td[text()='Unique value 2']//preceding-sibling::td)+2]
```

Is there any easier way?
Problem is that structure of table may change in time, but needed value will always be next to unique

Comment: Am I missing something? In your provided XML I **do not** see a `<a>` element, but in your provide XPath you test on this element.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried to cut off some elements to make example more clear but forgot tu cut them from XPath. Corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `preceding-sibling`, use `following-sibling`:

```
//td[text()="unique value 2"]/following-sibling::td[1]
```